# What are the most important errata for a new D&D 4E group?

Tags: dnd-4e, new-players, new-gm, books, errata

I plan to start a new D&D 4E game soon. None of us have played before, and we'll be starting at level 1. Are there any important errata that I should know about and inform my players?

I know there are errata documents available, but I'm looking for a distillation of the most important ones for level 1 characters.

Books owned: Core 3 plus PHB2, DMG2 and Rules Compendium.

Players: Eladrin Wizard, Human Warlord, Shifter Avenger, Goliath Warden

Comment: What books do you have?  If you are using the new Essentials books then you have no need for errata.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Rules Compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Product.aspx?x=dnd/products/dndacc/247530000) has all the updated rules for the core system, like changes to skills and skill challenge DCs and whatnot. You should pick that up if you don't mind buying another book.

Changes to the races and classes are pretty specific. Do you mind editing the question to list what your players are planning to play?

I think the biggest change outside of specific power tweaks to the classes in the first Player's Handbook is that a rogue can apply his Sneak Attack damage once per turn rather than once per round.

Comment: The new magic missile is a fairly significant level 1 change as well.

Comment: The recalibration of DCs for skill checks strikes me as very important as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another recommendation picking up the Rules Compendium, as most of the skills were rewritten.

The errata is broken down by book.  It's pretty easy to skim through and look for sections that are relevant to your game.  At a minimum, I would review the PH sections for the classes your players are using, as class features and first level powers may have changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just getting started, I'd recommend the Rules Compendium and a D&D Insider subscription.

The Rules compendium is good for at-the-table research, but I find it far simpler to just use the Character Builder rather than slog through all the various errata for the book.

Comment: Hi! @Allen Gould .... what should I look for, once I have my D&D insider? as a newbie!

Comment: @Eilleen If memory serves, between the Compendium and Insider, you should be up-to-date ruleswise. (And don't forget rule #0 - the DM is always right!)

Comment: xD ok!... So basically if I dowload the Hanbooks and MonsterManuals from D&DI they will be up-to-date?

Comment: It's been a while since I've looked at the 4E stuff, but they should be keeping their errata up to date. (Not sure if you can download entire books though.) Best of luck!